# How to set auto_increment_offset and auto_increment_increment for a single database

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

Is it possible to set auto_increment_offset and auto_increment_increment variables only for a single database without affecting any other database?

The reason why I want this is I am implementing a master master replication on a database but I have a cloud VPS with 30 domains and its databases. So I need to set this variables for a single database without affecting the other databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is a global variable. [You can set it per session](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-master.html) though, so the PHP software could be written to set it each time the database connection is opened.

> If the local value is set, the new value affects `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns for all tables into which new rows are inserted by the current user for the duration of the session, unless the values are changed during that session.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the code to set on each database load and working fine now.